# office 365 api generate a guest link for MyFiles

Tags: api, office365

I am trying to access from an MVC application, the OneDrive files from my office 365 account.
What I need is to give my application user the possibility to edit a .docx file, in their browser.

I used Office 365 APIs Preview, to get the list of files, and their properties, but I don't know how to allow the user to edit that file in his browser.

A solution to this problem could be to share the file with different user of my application, by creating a guest link.
From the office365 portal this is a simple task: 
- OneDrive, select the file -> manage -> share with -> get a link, the link can have read only or read write rights.

I don’t know how to create this link from the APIs.

Can you please tell me how can I generate this guest link or if there is a different solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, I don't think this can be done in a supported way.

There is a real risk that if you figure out the URL structure, that the structure could change. I suggest that you make a feature request by using [UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/). It would be preferable that the REST API and the client objects construct this URL for you.

With that said, if you take the sharing link, and place it into a browser window, the link will redirect to Word Online with the document in the browser. Take a look at the structure of the URL in the Word Online browser window. You could use that as a template, and along with the information from the File.Url property from the Office 365 API Preview, you may be able to put together a URL to that file. Expect that this approach would not be supported and would be subject to URL structure changes.

If other people find that this would be a useful feature, please use [UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/) to let us know.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the solution available for now to build the url. 
I check the UserVoice and there are already some question on this subject.